# App specific settings in logi options+ for new outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, logitech-options+

I use Logi Options+ (with MX Keys and MX Master 3) on Windows 10.

I've recently switched to new Outlook and can not find it in the application list for Logi Options+, how I can find it?

---

update: just doing a bit more research, I've learned that New Outlook is an app from the store and installed in `C:\program files\windowsApps` to which I don't have access, having a company pc. So I can't select the app in Logi Options+

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you opt out of the new Outlook, as described in [Toggling out of the new Outlook for Windows preview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/toggling-out-of-the-new-outlook-for-windows-preview-ec102b39-5727-418e-ae1f-a1805434640c)? You can also in *Settings > Apps*, find "Outlook (New)" in the list, click the dots to the right and choose Uninstall. Create a System Restore point before doing anything. Do you have administrator rights?

Comment: In Windows 11, I have the New Outlook in my LogiOptions+, so try to uninstall and reinstall LogiOptions+. I don't have access either to `C:\program files\windowsApps` (even though I own the PC). https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtV0U.jpg

Comment: I tested now on my Windows 10 PC, and the new Outlook appears in LogiOptions+. So it must have to do with your companies policies. Try to ask IT to install it for you from an Admin account.

Comment: If @1NN's suggestion for IT doesn't work, you can manually create the same button functions by capturing the requisite hot keys and manually assigning them to the mouse and keyboard buttons

Comment: @JW0914 could you please explain how exactly that can be done, and how it'll be app specific? (I'm stuck with app specific settings: same mouse buttons to behave differently in new outlook than in other tools)

Comment: @MátéJuhász I spaced and realized you have to first select the application lol it's not an Admin permissions issue, so reinstalling Logi Options+ should resolve the issue =] `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps` isn't accessible even if the user is a part of the `Administrators` group since Logi Options+ isn't run with Admin permissions and never should be. Outlook (New) shows in my applications list, even though it's not installed _(just an FYI, it lacks a myriad of options the Outlook 365 desktop program offers, which is why I immediately switched back)_

Comment: The last software update is from 22 Feb 2024: Check if this resolves your issue. Version is: 1.64.527952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis

I have made a test on a Win 10 PC which had neither New Outlook nor LogiOptions+ installed. I installed both on a local user profile without any specific rights.

- LogoOptions+ needs an Admin password to install, and will be available to all users
- The new Outlook, **IF** it is installed through the Store, is available only to the current user.

After such steps, `Outlook (new)` is available in LogiOptions+.

[image]

However, I strongly suspect that on your PC the new Outlook was installed through one of the [deployment methods for Enterprises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/outlook/get-started/deployment-new-outlook#other-deployment-options). So it won't be registered as a Store app, and LogiOptions+ won't detect it.

That said, **the best option would be if you could convince a colleague from IT to install LogiOptions+ for you on your PC**, using an IT admin password. I can't test this though and don't know if it will work.

### Workarounds I've tried (and failed)

- If you navigate to `shell:AppsFolder`, you will find a link to `Outlook (new)`. But unfortunately, there's no way to access virtual folders from within the `Add other Application` Menu in LogiOptions+.
- Setting a Desktop Shortcut and selecting this from LogiOptions+ works for 'classic' Windows applications, but for Store apps it won't work: the Shortcut simply isn't visible from within LogiOptions+.

### Things you can try

- If you are allowed to run unsigned executables, create an .exe (with bat2exe or something) which runs Outlook by calling

  ```
    Start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.OutlookforWindows
  ```

  Then address that .exe from LogiOptions+. (The `OutlookForWindows_8wekyb3d8bbwe` part might be different on your system: get it by looking in `%localappdata%\Packages\`).
- There's a freeware called [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) which can program up to 5 Mouse Buttons according to the application used. Maybe it's worth a shot. (I have not tested it).

Comment: Thanks for the investigation! I've reinstalled Logi Options+ and still can't see the new outlook. And indeed I can see it in shell:AppsFolder only. I haven't yet tried to create the .exe launching new Outlook

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was signaled to Logitech  in the post
[Options+ is not recognizing the new Outlook 365](https://logitech.uservoice.com/forums/925117-logi-options/suggestions/46760275-options-is-not-recognizing-the-new-outlook-365)
from 2023-06-09, but was never answered.

Your only option for the moment seems to not use
the problematic new Outlook, which for the moment
is still possible until end 2024.
If you can manage that on this company computer, this might give you some time to wait for a fix.
You should also contact Logitech Support, to add
your voice to this demand of a fix.

Opting out of the new Outlook is described in the article
[Toggling out of the new Outlook for Windows preview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/toggling-out-of-the-new-outlook-for-windows-preview-ec102b39-5727-418e-ae1f-a1805434640c). Some of the methods need local
administrator permissions.

- Unselect the toggle in the new Outlook app.
- Registry (`regedit`) : In key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences`,
  set `UseNewOutlook` to `0`.
- In *Settings > Apps*, find "Outlook (New)"
  in the list, click the dots to the right and choose
  Uninstall.

I would suggest to create a System Restore point before
doing any of the above.

Note that Microsoft is still evolving rapidly the
new Outlook app, so the above may stop working at
anytime and without notice.

Comment: You obviously don't have Logi Options+, otherwise you would realize that the post you link addresses a DIFFERENT problem. As per my comment above, the new Outlook IS available in Logi Options+, so it's evidently a problem related to the OP's system configuration: it is THAT which needs to be addressed

Comment: @1NN: I don't know of a solution to making Logi Options+ work in the new Outlook. I don't have Logi Options+ but I do have the new Outlook. Therefore I suggested simply going back to the classic Outlook, as a stopgap measure. This is a different direction than yours (which requires administrator permissions), but both approaches may be handicapped by the fact that this is a company computer and a solution might be difficult in a rigid environment.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned that it's a company PC and that you don't have access to the folder. Without access, Logi Options+ is unable to detect it and you are unable to manually select it. The only solution is to contact your company's administrator to see if you could get access to the required folder or if they could add it for you.

Comment: I don't have a Logitech mouse however there should be a setting for global which applies for all apps, so if that works for you then use that.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Logi Options+. Then check if you are able to manually add New Outlook by clicking **Add applications**, see https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023184154-Configure-Application-Specific-settings-with-Logitech-Options-software.

If you have done the above and still cannot find New Outlook, chances are that it is not yet supported. And you can try to contact Logi for further confirmation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've the latest version, and I can't find it in the list of "add applications" (that's why I've posted my question)